# Saving user's input to create two lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm a beginner in python and I am trying to write a program that will loop for a user to create a list of items and their costs. Once the loop is closed I would like the items and their associated costs to be displayed. I am stuck on how to keep the list from forgetting the previous input(s). Currently, it will only show the last input item and cost. Any help would be really appreciated!

```
Item = []

Cost = []

Add_again = 'Yes'

while Add_again == 'Yes':

    Item = [item for item in input("One of the items you already have is: ").split()]

    Cost  = [float(item) for item in input("What did it cost? $").split()]

    Add_again = input('Is there another item you would like to add? "Yes" if so: ')


print("Item\tCost")

print("---------------------------")

for Item, Cost in zip(Item, Cost):

    print(Item, Cost)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Item = []

Cost = []


def add_again_item(name,value): #=== Parameters to add to the 2 lists
    Item.append(name)
    Cost.append(value)

while True:
    item=input("Enter your item: ")
    val=int(input("What did it cost, enter in number of dollars $:"))
    add_again_item(item,val) #== Calling the function and adding the items to the lists
    if input('Is there another item you would like to add? "Yes" if so: ').lower()=="no": #=== If input is no
        break


print("Item\tCost")

print("---------------------------")

for Item, Cost in zip(Item, Cost):

    print(Item,"\t", Cost)
```

Instead of function, you can also do: Right where the function was called

```
Item.append(name)
Cost.append(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use input for a list. Append it to the empty lists -

```
item_input = input("One of the items you already have is: ")
Item.append(item_input)

cost_input  = input("What did it cost? $")
Cost.append(cost_input)
```